# Xamarin forms app long loading if resolve dependency

Tags: android, xamarin, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

Long first loading of instance of any type registered in Resolver.

I tried to load random type in background using Thread and BackgroundWorker during base page opening and in MainActivit. The problem remained in any case. Only now during the application loading.

Appp.xaml.cs

```
if (!Resolver.IsSet)
{
    var resolverContainer = new SimpleContainer();
    resolverContainer.Register<ICartService, CartService>(); 
    Resolver.SetResolver(resolverContainer.GetResolver());
}
```

And when i tried to get instanse of ICartService it's take 3+ seconds just for this operation.

It looks like:
    `Resolver.Resolve<ICartService>();`

Comment: What does CartService do in the constructor? Are subsequent calls to resolve this service faster?

Comment: @Cheesebaron Any servise loading so long. Even empty one. After first call everything works fine for any type.

Comment: SimpleContainer, which library does that come from?

Comment: @Cheesebaron it's Xamarin.Forms default container. The same situation with unity container.